# Format issue with the output file of pytesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, tesseract, python-tesseract

I was trying to extract text from a image using pytesseract.

I want the output file to be in the same format the image being processed.

By format I mean the output text to be arranged in rows and columns as the input image.

I have tried the following code but the output file looks nothing like the input but the text recognition is mostly accurate.

#### Code

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/bin/tesseract'

custom_config = r'-c preserve_interword_spaces=1 --oem 1 --psm 1 -l eng'
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open(r'_0.png'), config=custom_config, output_type=Output.DICT)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# clean up blanks
df1 = df[(df.conf!='-1')&(df.text!=' ')&(df.text!='')]
# sort blocks vertically
sorted_blocks = df1.groupby('block_num').first().sort_values('top').index.tolist()
for block in sorted_blocks:
    curr = df1[df1['block_num']==block]
    sel = curr[curr.text.str.len()>3]
    char_w = (sel.width/sel.text.str.len()).mean()
    prev_par, prev_line, prev_left = 0, 0, 0
    text = ''
    for ix, ln in curr.iterrows():
        # add new line when necessary
        if prev_par != ln['par_num']:
            text += '\n'
            prev_par = ln['par_num']
            prev_line = ln['line_num']
            prev_left = 0
        elif prev_line != ln['line_num']:
            text += '\n'
            prev_line = ln['line_num']
            prev_left = 0

        added = 0  # num of spaces that should be added
        if ln['left']/char_w > prev_left + 1:
            added = int((ln['left'])/char_w) - prev_left
            text += ' ' * added 
        text += ln['text'] + ' '
        prev_left += len(ln['text']) + added + 1
    text += '\n'
    print(text)
```

#### Input Image

[image]

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Please put the code as text in your question and not as an image. [Why to not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16496244)

Comment: @K450 I updated the question and added the code in text.

Comment: @K450 hey I am still waiting for your reply.

Comment: I think (not 100% sure) the noise in the input image is causing overlaps in detection as can be seen in this [image](https://imgur.com/a/s0E9Dwg) where I have drawn bounding boxes around the detections, and it might cause it to put detected text in wrong level or block. Try doing some image processing and denoising to clean the image before you feed it to detect text. Like dilation and erosion may help a bit and look for other ways to remove those black spots.

Comment: @thanks for the help, I tried to cleaning it up and also trimmed the borders but the text detection accuracy dropped significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - remove noise -> it will produce extra errors.

Next try different output. e.g. hocr is html/xml output with bounding boxes info, so you can get exact position on screen for OCR result.

If you do not need exact position, maybe easier would be postprocesing of txt output. E.g. tesseract 5 and tessdata_best produce this output

```
$ tesseract YaVQ3.jpg - --psm 6 --dpi 300 -c preserve_interword_spaces=1

2
wf
10020 Knut Bratli, Brandval          P.b. Chrysler       1936
10033 Erland Berg, Gjes&sen         P.b. Dodge        1939
10054 Edvart Sandmo, Gardvik         P.b. Opel          1937
10057 Hjalmar Aanerud, Vinger        P.b. Opel           1932
10075 Reidar Holth, Flisa                P.b. Volvo         . 1960
10076 Einar Bredalen, Braskereidfoss   P.b. Dodge        1929
10077 Reidar Holth, Flisa            P.b. Volkswagen    1961
10089 Sor-Odal Bulldozerdrift, Skarnes Lb. White         1944   "
10090 Arne Radford, Galterud            Lb. Ford            1939
10093 Sverre Langbraten, Brandval       L.b. Citroén          1950
10096 Karl Tuhus, Skotterud          P.b. Chrysler       1936
10101 Gunnar Bie-Larsen, Kongsvinger P.b. Ford    :   ©1961
10110 Martin Albertsen, Flisa           Pb. Opel       .   1960
10111 Alf @degaard, Kongsvinger         P.b. Volkswagen      1958
10112 Asbjern Elverhoi, Kongsvinger    Pb. Ford          1961
10114 Olav Sunde jr., Skarnes       ¢    P.b. Plymouth       1937
10116 John Erichsen, Skarnes          P.b. Ford          1960
10118 Ole Hasleengen, Véler    \        Pb. Morris         1931
10120 Harald Eggen, Vinger    \       P.b. Peugeot        1938
10121 Ola N. Berg, Gjesisen             Pb. Ford            1960
10125 Reldar Rapstad, Roverud            Pb. Ford             1954     Pp
10129 Erling Johnsrud, Skarnes           Pb. Overland         1939
10130 Reidar Vangen, Disend          P.b. Hudson        1947      v
10133 Oddvar Lilleseth, Skarnes      V.b. Ford        1934
10136 Hans K. Kolbjornsrud, Austmarka P.b. Volvo         1939
10140 Rolv Snare, Kongsvinger         P.h. Mercedes Benz 1950
10143 Olaf Storberget, Grue Finnskog L.b. Land Rover    1951
10146 Helge Strand, Magnor            P.b. Hudson         1946
10148 Arne Hagan, Brandval             Pb. Volkswagen’    1957
10159 Brodbelfoss, E.verk, Vinger        P.b. Chevrolet        1939
10160 Lauritz Hove, Sander           Pb. Ford          1959
10161 Rolf Johnsen, Matrand           Lb. Ford         * 1937
10168 Sten Sooth Knutsen, Skotterud    Pb. Volkswagen     1962
10170 Odd Norli, Knapper               P.b. Buick           1938
10175 Gustav Solvang, Kongsvinger     L.b. Chevrolet       1939         4
10180 Trygve Wolden, Kongsvinger    Pb. Dodge        1920
10182 Kongsv. Handelsgartneri, Kongsv. Stb. Opel            1957
10186 Oddvar Berget, Namni             Lb. Fordson         1933
10188 Sander Idrettslag, Sander     .    Buss Austin      +1951
10185 Karl O. Halvorsen, Br.foss        L.b. Hanomag       1955
NN                                    -
3
      :                                 ll
v                                -—
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as you said I found post processing of txt output to be easier then pre processing the image.